# Are data passed to mex functions guaranteed non-aliasing?

Tags: c, matlab, mex

Suppose a mex function is called this way

```
ret = aMexFunction(foo, foo); % same data for both inputs
```

And in the mex function:

```
void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                  int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) 
{
    bar(mxGetData(prhs[0]), mxGetData(prhs[1]));
}
```

but `bar` is defined as:

```
bar(Type *restrict ptr1, Type *restrict ptr2)
{         ^^^^^^^^             ^^^^^^^^   // could this be a problem?
    doSomeThing();
}
```

Comment: Elaborate what happens in bar with those arguments?

Comment: @this bar assumes `restrict`ed pointers, so if `mxGetData(prhs[0])` and `mxGetData(prhs[0])` returns the same underlying storage location, it's UB.

Comment: @Praetorian http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/matlab-mex-in-place-editing  According to this link, Matlab does not duplicate data when it's passed to a mex function. And it's not about writing to aliased  `restrict`ed pointers only, reading from aliased `restrict`ed pointers can also cause nasty results.

Comment: @user3528438 Please post a minimal correct example. Try not to use external function as it will obscure the problem.

Comment: @this http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxgetdata.html?refresh=true   `mxGetData` is a mex API function that returns the pointer to the first element of a `mxArray`. It returns `void *` rather than `double *` compared with `mxGetPr`. And this is a conceptual question regarding documented/undocumented feature of a programming language design, so MCVE is not useful.

Comment: I don't see any reason to link to an external resource for this question. You example is convoluted, especially since restrict qualifier is used.

Comment: @user3528438 Yes, you're right. But you still have `const` pointers, so `bar` shouldn't be changing the pointers you pass to it, and `restrict` shouldn't matter. I don't see a problem. If you want to in-place edit data, there's lots of information on Yair Altman's blog, or on the cssm newsgroup, but I'm sure you're aware that that's unsupported. If you call `mxUnshareArray` on both `prhs[0]` and `prhs[1]` you might end up copying the data twice if there's an external reference to the mxArray alive, or a single copy if there isn't. But in either case, the data `bar` will not be overlapping

Comment: @Praetorian I'm not sure if reading from aliased restricted pointers causes UB. But this is a separate question and I won't try to ask about it here.

Comment: First, interesting question, and your example is quite clear.  If the question is does `(T*)ptr1==(T*)ptr2`, then the answer is yes, because the two pointers `prhs[0]` and `prhs[1]` are equal.  If the question is can you operate on data in `prhs[]`, then the answer is carefully and others have posted links.  Also, `mxGetData` does NOT return a `const void*`, even for `const mxArray`.

Answer (score 0):

You only need restricted pointers when the pointers are not const, as only when one is written to will aliasing become an issue. Inputs to mex functions are const, and that constness should be passed on to calling functions. The input data arrays are not guaranteed to point to unaliased memory locations, because MATLAB assumes the inputs won't be changed, as they shouldn't be.